# Select2 with remote datasource dropdown show "searching... - undefined" and then "The results could not be loaded" after select

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use select2 4.0.5 with ajax. It work well if I search and select result on dropdown.

But after select one value on dropdown, if I reopen dropdown again (click on select2 object) dropdown show "searching... - undefined" and then "The results could not be loaded"

Comment: do you have code example? fiddle or code snippet that shows what you described would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it.

"searching... - undefined" : on templateResult i add check result.loading

```
templateResult : function (result) {
 if (result.loading) 
   return "Searching...";
   return result.text + " - " + result.description; 
}
```

On dropdown reopen after select, I found ajax data params.term is blank when dropdown reopen. It fix by

```
ajax: {
  ... 
  data: function (params) {
    var query = {
      term: params.term || $('#CurrencyID').select2('data')[0].text
    }
}
```